# Extensions of quasicoherent sheaves are quasicoherent.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Harts theorem 5.7: Given an exact sequence $0 \to \mathscr F_1 \to \mathscr F_2 \to \mathscr F_3 \to 0 $ of sheaves on $X = \mathrm{spec} A$, if $\mathscr F_1$ and $\mathscr F_3$ are quasicoherent, then so is $\mathscr F_2$.

We get an exact sequence $0 \to M_1 \to M_2 \to M_3 \to 0 $ (where each is the module of global sections of each $\mathscr F$, and then we get the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \tilde M_1 @>>> \tilde M_2 @>>> \tilde M_3 @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> \mathscr F_1 @>>> \mathscr F_2 @>>> \mathscr F_3 @>>> 0 \\
\end{CD}
$$

Where does the middle morphism come from? The other two are isomorphisms from the equivalence of quasicoherent sheaves and $A$-modules, but where does the middle one come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $X = \text{Spec}(A)$ the functor $\Gamma(X,-): {\mathscr O}_X\text{-Mod}\to A\text{-Mod}$ is right adjoint to the sheafification functor $\widetilde{(-)}: A\text{-Mod}\to {\mathscr O}_X\text{-Mod}$. In particular, for any ${\mathscr O}_X$-module ${\mathscr F}$ with global sections $M$ you have a canonical and natural counit morphism $\widetilde{M}\to{\mathscr F}$. This gives the transformations in (as well as the commutativity of) your diagram. To see the exactness of the upper row, you need to apply Proposition 5.6 in Hartshorne.

*Explicitly*, suppose $M$ is an $A$-module, ${\mathscr F}$ is an ${\mathscr O}_X$-module and $\varphi: M\to {\mathscr F}(X)$ is given. Then, by definition, given any $f\in A$ the sections ${\mathscr F}(D_f)$ are a module over ${\mathscr O}_X(D_f) = A_f$, hence $M\to {\mathscr F}(X)\to{\mathscr F}(D_f)$ extends canonically to a morphism $M_f\to {\mathscr F}(D_f)$ of $A_f$-modules. As $\widetilde{M}(D_f)=M_f$ by definition, these constitute the desired extension $\widetilde{M}\to{\mathscr F}$.

Comment: Why are they adjoint? It seems that by the way he just skips over it that there should be a less abstract argument (because as far as I'm aware, he doesn't prove adjointess?)

Comment: @fhyve: I added some details

Comment: @fhyve Adjointness is Ex. 5.3. Not the first or last time he uses an exercise without comment!